# VirtualBox установить в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Virtualbox не хочет устанавливаться на Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Гугл выдал несколько гайдов, что только не делал. После команд

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1
```

появляется такое:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
virtualbox-6.1 : Depends: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
              Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
              Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not installable
              Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Может кто подскажет как победить эту проблему и установить VirtualBox?

Comment: sudo apt update делал?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS выдаёт `E: Package 'virtualbox-6.1' has no installation candidate` ...

Comment: А в менеджере приложений виртуалбокса разве нет? напиши просто virtualbox, без 6.1

Comment: пробовал по-разному, и без 6.1 и без .1

Comment: А ты репозиторий от оракла-то добавил?

Comment: Честно говоря, очень много всяких разный гайдов перепробовал. Если есть ссыл на актуальный и рабочий, был бы признателен. У меня не очень много опыта в Ubuntu